# jsr 303 (hibernate validator 4) and spring 2.5.x

Tags: spring, bean-validation

How can I configure my Spring 2.5.x application to utilize the JSR 303 validation (hibernate validator 4x) ? I'm using Maven, and update the version of hibernate validator to 4.x, though when my Spring HibernateDaoSupport saves a model thats annotated with constraints, even if the object fails the constraints, I don't get an exception thrown (which used to happen with Hibernate validator 3x). Is there additional configuration needed?

Answer (score 4):

I used [this](http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/) excellent tutorial. Might be useful as a checklist?